# Angular 6 regexp to test for uppercase, lowercase, special char is not working

Tags: regex, angular6

I am trying to do a simple check if a password has an uppercase, lowercase, special char and number, but whether I use a switch case or a series of if else conditionals, it drops all the way to "can't recognize the char" conditional.

Why?

The following are my declarations:

```
  public str: string;
  public lowerCaseLetter: boolean;
  public upperCaseLetter: boolean;
  public specialChar: boolean;
  public numChar: boolean;
  public specialCharPattern = new RegExp(
    /[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/g
  );
  public lowerCharPattern = new RegExp(/a-z/g);
  public upperCharPattern = new RegExp(/A-Z/g);
  public numCharPattern = new RegExp(/0-9/g);
```

I have also tried:

```
  public specialCharPattern = new RegExp(
    /[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/
  );
  public lowerCharPattern = new RegExp("/a-z/");
  public upperCharPattern = new RegExp("/A-Z/");
  public numCharPattern = new RegExp("/0-9/");
```

I have also tried:

```
public specialCharPattern = /[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/;
public lowerCharPattern = /a-z/;
public upperCharPattern = /A-Z/;
public numCharPattern = /0-9/;
```

The following is the onKeyUp handler:

```
  onKeyUp($event) {
  this.str = $event.target.value;
  console.log(this.str);
  if (this.lowerCharPattern.test(this.str)) {
    this.lowerCaseLetter = true;
    console.log("lower case");
  } else if (this.upperCharPattern.test(this.str)) {
    this.upperCaseLetter = true;
    console.log("upper case");
  } else if (this.specialCharPattern.test(this.str)) {
    this.specialChar = true;
    console.log("special char");
  } else if (this.numCharPattern.test(this.str)) {
    this.numChar = true;
    console.log("number");
  } else {
    console.log("can't recognize the char");
  }
  this.str = "";
}
```

The following is a portion of the html:

```
<label for="password"
    >Please enter a password
    <input
      type="password"
      class="form-control"
      [(ngModel)]="model.password"
      #password="ngModel"
      [ngClass]="{
        'is-invalid': f.submitted && password.invalid
      }"
      name="password"
      placeholder="Password"
      (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)"
      required
      minlength="6"
    />min. length of 6 characters
  </label>
```

I can see in the console that whatever I type is what is passing through the onKeyUp, but it doesn't stop on any condition. Also, I expect "this.str" to be cleared with every key that is typed - this.str = ""; but it just continues. Is this because $event.target.value passes the entire input field?

As usual, thanks in advance

Comment: The `$event.target.value` will contain the complete string, not just the entered (or deleted or whatever) character. So your regular expressions will still check the complete (candidate) password for the rules. Personally I would instead use an array to check that every element of the array matches one character and all characters in the input string match one entry in the array.

Comment: `new RegExp("/a-z/")` must be `/[a-z]/`. Same fix is required for the other regexps. Use a character class, not a RegExp constructor. No `g` modifier is necessary (it is harmful). ``public specialCharPattern = /[~`!#$%^&*+=[\]';,\/{}|\\":<>?-]/;`` `public upperCharPattern = /[A-Z]/; public numCharPattern = /[0-9]/;`

Comment: @wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew - thank you for replying. I have updated the code to show what I have tried, that did not work either. The conditional still returns "can't recognize the char" - is there something wrong with my conditional statement?

Comment: Again, NOT `new RegExp(/0-9/g)`, BUT `/[0-9]/`. `[...]` creates a character class that matches any single char defined inside the square brackets. `/A-Z/` matches an `A-Z` string.

Comment: @corion - thank you for replying. I have tried public pswArr: any = []; this.pswArr = $event.target.value; if (this.lowerCharPattern.test(this.pswArr[0])) and the conditional still returns "can't recognize the char"

Comment: @wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew - yes, I have tried public lowerCharPattern = /a-z/; public upperCharPattern = /A-Z/; public numCharPattern = /0-9/; - same result

Comment: So, you have  NOT tried what I said. `public lowerCharPattern = /[a-z]/; public upperCharPattern = /[A-Z]/; public numCharPattern = /[0-9]/;`

Answer (score 0):

As a result of both comments from @wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew and @corion, I was able to make it work with the following code:

```
this.str = $event.target.value;
this.pswArr = this.str.split("");
for (let x = 0; x <= this.pswArr.length; x++) {
  if (this.lowerCharPattern.test(this.pswArr[x])) {
    this.lowerCaseLetter = true;
    this.lowerCharArr[0] = 1;
    this.strngMeter += 1;
    // console.log("lower case");
  }
  if (this.upperCharPattern.test(this.pswArr[x])) {
    this.upperCaseLetter = true;
    this.upperCharArr[0] = 1;
    this.strngMeter += 1;
    // console.log("upper case");
  }
  if (this.specialCharPattern.test(this.pswArr[x])) {
    this.specialChar = true;
    this.specialCharArr[0] = 1;
    this.strngMeter += 1;
    // console.log("special char");
  }
  if (this.numCharPattern.test(this.pswArr[x])) {
    this.numChar = true;
    this.numCharArr[0] = 1;
    this.strngMeter += 1;
    // console.log("number");
  }
  // console.log("this.pswArr: ", this.pswArr);
}
```

Comment: This code feels very confused. You iterate over `this.str.length`, but you use  indices from `pswArr`. Also, you store ` $event.target.value` in `this.pswArr` - why don't you use a plain lexical variable like `let pswStr = $event.target.value;` ?

Comment: @corion - I have rewritten the code, but for the strngMeter, it is counting when I focus or blur from the input field (tab key) - I do not understand why it is doing that. Either way, do you like this code better. I am trying to follow part of your advise to iterate over an array